# How to make sure text inside a column is fully visible using Playwright?

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I have a table in my web page. Let us assume that one of the columns has a very long text, and the column is at its default width.

```
expect(self.page.locator('text=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')).\
to_be_visible(timeout=20 *1000)
```

The code passes, as `Playwright` can find the text in the HTML.

How can I make sure that a human can see all the letters and that nothing is hidden?

Comment: You could try and use innerText. So something like `expect(self.page.locator('text=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ').inner_text()).\
to_be_visible(timeout=20 *1000)`

Comment: if text is static, you could use visual comparisons https://playwright.dev/docs/test-snapshots

Comment: @Basti that assertion doesn't work. `ValueError: Unsupported type: <class 'str'>`